# Why does my list contain its original items when I set it to a new List<T>();?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities: `WorkCategory` and `Certificate`.

A work category has many certificates.

I have a method to save certificates to a work category:

```
    public void AddInductionCertificatesToWorkCategory(InductionWorkCategory workCategory, List<Certificate> certificates)
    {
        workCategory.Certificates = new List<Certificate>();

        foreach (var certificate in certificates)
        {
            var dbCertificate = _db.Certificates.Single(v => v.Id == certificate.Id);
            workCategory.Certificates.Add(dbCertificate);
        }

        _db.InductionWorkCategories.Attach(workCategory);
        _db.Entry(workCategory).State = EntityState.Modified;

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The only relevant line is the first: `workCategory.Certificates = new List<Certificate>();` When this line is executed, `workCategory.Certificates` still has its original items.

What is it about EF/dynamic proxies that makes this happen?

Also, if I set a breakpoint on that line and look at the collection, it works.

Edit: I'm not looking for a solution or work around, I'm just curious as to whats happening under the covers.

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you're not checking the value before the code is run? i.e. the breakpoint is on the new List<Certificate>() line and you're checking the value then, rather than the line after it's run? Your code should work absolutely fine.

Comment: If you are still convinced there is an error and setting `workCategory.Certificates = new List<Certificate>()` doesn't set the list to the newly created object then take a look at the setter of the `Certificates` property. Mabye it does nothing at all, i.e. `set { }`.

Comment: Are you able to call [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx) on the existing list instead?

Comment: I am guessing workCategory.Certificates is not really a List, but IEnumerable, which is lazily loaded, and that you through debug, looking at the values, will load its contents?

Comment: We're talking about EF entities, so there is no setter body. The code is fine, but the error I've described happens, unless I peak at the collection before the line is executed.

Comment: do you have access to ObjectContext?

Answer (score 0):

If you expose your ObjectContext then you can force a refresh on your statements. It would look like this.

```
_DbContext.ObjectContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, workCategory);
```

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't answer my question.. Sorry mate